# Want to override child element css property by parent element

Tags: css

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
</div></div>
```

In CSS, "child" class has its own bg color, that I can't change. I want to apply "parent" class bg color to container. So, Is there any CSS trick to override "child" bg color by "parent" bg color.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A child class is above a parent class. My thought is, remove the child class background unless you cannot. What can you change?

Answer (score 21):

!important will override any inline background color applied, let me know if this works

```
.parent > .child {
    background-color: transparent !important;
 }
```

Comment: They're not talking about inline background color, they said: "'child' **class** has its own bg color"

Comment: `background-color:transparent` makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
.parent .child {
    background-color: inherit !important; // can also use "transparent"
}
```

Use `!important` only if nothing else works.

Comment: Thats not what they want, even though it would work. also, .parent > .child

Comment: @Cam Sorry, was in a rush. Fixed.

Comment: The problem is, they want the parent background to override the child background.

Comment: @Cam Yes, this does that.

Comment: The first part of the statement says "In CSS, "child" class has its own bg color, that I can't change. "

Comment: @Cam They *can* change it if they include this after the first .child declaration. This is tested and it answers the question.

Comment: Also, i did not -1. You needed to address the !important attribute.

Comment: !important also overrides inline code if any is used and the person has no access to change inline code.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_bgcolor.asp bgcolor is a inline attribute. When someone uses bgcolor and not background-color it ussually tells me they are dealing with inline code they cant override.

Comment: @Cam You're right; but they said, "In CSS,..." so they're not talking about the inline HTML attribute. No offense, but please read the question carefully again.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the CSS using jQuery, although it's inelegant. So, if you have HTML

```
<div class="parent">
        <div class="child">
</div></div>
```

and CSS:

```
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.child {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
```

this jQuery will find the parent background color and apply it to the child:

```
$('.child').on('click',  function(event) {
    var bg = $(this).parent().css("background-color"); // finds background color of parent
    $(this).css("background-color", bg);  //  applies background color to child
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/37GVr/)

Comment: Well, it seems to me like user is asking for a way to change the background color of the child depending on the color of the parent without the ability to control the CSS. JS can do that, although as I mentioned in the first sentence, it certainly isn't ideal

Comment: You could use the `inherit` CSS value, or `transparent` if nothing else.

Comment: what's the benefit of using an external library? In plain js: `this.style.backgroundColor=this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor`

Comment: ok, but people might not have a click event at all, isn't it? 
other solutions are simpler, in general if something can be done in css, we should instead of writing javascript. 
because multiple lines of logic in JS can be done in 1 line in css, and writing more code may result in more bugs. 
with css3, we can do a lot in less. just a thought.