# Css override child color from parent

Tags: html, css

I have following css

```
.red {
    color: red !important;
}
.yellow {
    color: yellow;
 }
```

In html

```
<div class="red">
    red
    <span class="yellow">override this</span>
</div>
```

How do I override child color from parent? I can't use inherit. I have a condition that red is shown otherwise yellow. Please help me.

Comment: Use the selector `.red .yellow` and set it to the value you like

Comment: I can't update child.  can I change css by only updating parent?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297085/want-to-override-child-element-css-property-by-parent-element

Comment: Why can't you update the css? Unfortunately this is your only option unless you want to write some JavaScript. Which I won't recommend because it would have bad impact on performance

Comment: The selector worked thanks. I can update css but can't update the child. I can already using react

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would suggest

Here is my html

```
<div class="red">
    red
    <span class="yellow">override this</span>
</div>

  <span class="yellow">this will be yellow</span>
  
  <span class="red">this will be red</span>
```

this is my css

```
.red .yellow {
    color: red !important;
}

.red  {
    color: red !important;
}

.yellow {
    color: yellow
 }
```

As you can see the yellow is overridden by red

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of this answer is about **not using** `!important` attribute.

You can do it simply using `CSS parent-child` syntax, also combining the father to make it with the same CSS properties (in our case), like this:

```css
.red, .red > .yellow {
    color: red;
}

.yellow {
    color: yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div class="red">
    red
    <span class="yellow">override this</span>
</div>

<p>Should be <b class="red">red</b></p>

<p>Should be <b class="yellow">yellow</b></p>
```